# div без или с ними не увеличивает height

Tags: html, css

fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhscokco/

Понимаю, что что-то не то, пробовал дивы с классами left-menu, main сделать с float, clear: both, и без float с overflow в итоге режет таблицу.
А в итоге надо чтобы оба дива эти растягивались спокойно, если таблица увеличивается.

```
<header>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<br style="clear: both">
</header>
<div class="content">
<div class="leftMenu"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="hotSpots">
    <div class="block1">
      <div class="icons">icon</div>
      <div class="table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>locations</td>
            <td>shares</td>
            <td>social</td>
            <td>redirect</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А о каких `div` идёт речь? о вертикальных или горизонтальных?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю так надо или нет , но ...

```css
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
}
header .logo {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
header .right {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .main {
  width: calc(100% - 104px);
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content .leftMenu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.hotSpots {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.hotSpots .block1 {
  padding: 30px 50px 50px 50px;
}
.hotSpots .table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hotSpots table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.hotSpots table tr:first-child {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.hotSpots table,
.hotSpots th,
.hotSpots td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</header>
<div class="clear" />
<div class="content">
  <div class="leftMenu"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="hotSpots">
      <div class="block1">
        <div class="icons">icon</div>
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>name</td>
              <td>locations</td>
              <td>shares</td>
              <td>social</td>
              <td>redirect</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а куда пропал то мой div с class left-menu

Comment: @unrealisted я просто скопировал ваш html и всё , ни чего не убирал